# Flexible COB LED LETTERS - how to connect and power

Tags: led, led-driver

I would like to ask for advice on a project I would like to do as a gift. I have purchased 12 flexible LED COB letters (150mA/DC2.8-3.0V/Ra>90) [from here](https://a.aliexpress.com/_m0mskJs).

I would simply like to connect and power them in series and would like to purchase a ready built suitable driver but I am unsure what I need. Ideally I would like to power it via usb connection.

Soldering the 12 letters in series is pretty much the limit of my electronic skills.
I'd really appreciate some advice.

Comment: also posted at https://s2.solveforum.com/threads/led-edison-letters.607098/

Comment: what did you buy exactly? ... why do you require a series connection?

Comment: use a DC-DC boost converter that can output 30v at 150ma. That's 4.5W of power, which will pull about 1A from USB, so you'll probably need a QC or PD trigger on the USB cable. Some USB "wall warts" will spit out 1A w/o any special handling, but some won't, so we can't say exactly what it will take. Should be doable though.

Comment: Hi this is what I’m wanting to connect, there are 10 in total and it doesn’t have to be connected in series I just thought that would be the easiest and least wire

Comment: https://a.aliexpress.com/_m0mskJs

Comment: Hi, the term "Edison" usually refer to the screw type of lightbulb. A web search for "Edison letters" bring up a bunch of images of historical letters by some guy with the same name. Might I suggest you edit the title of your question to something akin to "Flexibel COB LED letters, 3V/150mA how to wire" and put the product link in the question and perhaps an image.

Comment: Perfect idea sillis

Comment: Please [edit] your existing post rather than adding comments (as comments might get lost)

Comment: Connecting them in series won't work if they all take different amounts of current, which is entirely possible as they have different surface areas and hence probably different numbers of LEDs. But as usual with the likes of Aliexpress there's no real data that would help to understand whether they need a constant current driver or just a regulated voltage so there may be some guesswork involved.

Answer (score 2):

The letters operate on about 3V at up to 150 mA.
Brightness should be adequate at well below the maximum current.
I'll assume that they are designed for equal filament/segment brightness at the same current. If this is not the case then another approach is required.

To operate on USB power you will have to either operate them all in parallel, or have a USB / 5V to Vled converter

USB to various voltage converters are available, or you could use a "plug pack".

---

**Using plug pack or USB to higher voltage, or similar:**

If 12 are operated in series you need 3 x 12 = 36V or more.
While you can buy 40V supplies that may not be the best choice.

If you use two strings then you need >= 20V
If you use 3 strings you need > 12V - getting better.
4 strings of 3 require >= 10V per string, so 12V would be suitable.

12V suppplies are readily available.
You need a current rating of
Isupply = I_LED x number-of-strings
=  100 mA (say) x 4 = 400 mA.
A 1A, 12V  supply would be ample.

LED current increases exponentially with voltage across the LED.
Actual LED current is set by adding a series resistor.
I resistor = V/R = Vacross_resistor / Resistor resistance.
Vresistor is "what is left over from the 12V after the LEDs have taken their share".
Assume about 3V per LED.
3 in series = 9V.
V to drop across resistor is 12-9V = 3 V.
Resistor value = V/I = 3V / 0.1A = 30 Ohms.
A 27 or 33 Ohm resistor (standard values) in series with each string will produce something like what you want. Final value my need some playing.

Resistor wattage rating = V^2/R = 3 x 3 / 30 = 0.3 Watt.
Using 1 Watt resistors will keep them reliable and reasonably cool running.

---

**Powering directly from USB**

If operating all lights in parallel directly on USB 5V you need a series resistor per LED.

R = V/I - (Vsupply-Vled)/Iled = (5-3)/0.1 = 20 Ohms.
Use say 22 Ohms standard value.

Power in each resistor is
P = V^2/R = 2 x 2 / 20 = 0.2 watts per resistor.
One resistor per LED.
1/2 watt resistors would be suitable.

While it would notionally be possible to use a single resistor powering all LED's in parallel this is a really bad idea in practice and should be avoided.